# How do I make a full width picture extend, through using CSS, without effecting the quality of the picture?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have been doing some HTML and CSS and have come across a problem that I hope someone can help with.

I am trying to make a full width picture cover a whole Div without a significant loss of quality to the picture.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is similar to the following websites:

https://sso.godaddy.com/v1/?app=mya&realm=idp&

http://www.ugle.org.uk/

Both websites use a picture which quality seams to not dissolve through being expanded or contracted.

How is this done?

Any one know of any tutorials or have example code that they could show me. I have created a picture that can vary to the browsers window size but its quality is awful when the browser changes size.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: You need a large image. The referenced images are 1600x1015 and 1500x625. You can use the images via `<img>` or as a background image. What size of image are you using now? Where's your code?

Comment: Create the image in Photoshop and use the same exact size and a .png forma. It should not lose data. Resizing it in anyway small or large will cause it to lose quality.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy. There are a few ways to do this, but the most straightforward is to set the image as the background of the div, with the background size property set to cover: `background-size: cover;`

For example (CSS):

```
div {
  background: url('path/to/your/image.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Edit:** Addressing image quality:
You'd need to make sure your background image is equal to or larger than the div's dimensions. If it's smaller - it'll be stretched to fit (this degrading the quality).

Comment: This addresses part of the question, the other part being, how to limit quality degradation? Which also seems to be the most important part as OP has stated, _"I have created a picture that can vary to the browsers window size..."_ How they have done that? No idea. Might be responsive image or what you have posted above. We'll need to see their code to know for sure.

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: you can use CSS *Media Queries* to switch the `url` of the image between different resolutions of the same image, so users with high-res screens will get the highest quality image and users with smaller resolutions or phones will get a lighter version (which loads faster)